# Adding gnuplot package to Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

I've added the gnuplot MELPA package to Spacemacs by including `dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(gnuplot)` in the `~/.spacemacs` file. It installed the package the next time I opened it up, but I'm not getting any highlighting occuring in Spacemacs when I open a `.gp` file. Where's the best place to look to get this working?

Edit 1:

I added a layer called `plotting` to the private folder in `~/.emacs.d` I followed the outline for the finance layer and put

```
(setq plotting-packages
  '(              
    gnuplot-mode   
    ))
```

and

```
(defun plotting/init-gnuplot-mode ()   
  (use-package gnuplot-mode            
    :mode (("\\.gp$" . gnuplot-mode))))
```

in the `packages.el` file and

```
(spacemacs|defvar-company-backends gnuplot-mode)
```

in the `config.el` file.
I'm getting some syntax highlighting in `.gp` files now, but not all of it. Anything else I need to add to get full support?